# Why is my join query returning Malformed query?

Tags: soql, query, sql, inner-join

I have two tables -- RecordType and CventSession__c.  THe CventSession__c has a RecordTypeId field taht links back to the RecordType table.  How do I write a query to get the CventSession__c.ID and the RecordType.Description field?  I tried

```
select RecordTypeId, RecordType.Description from CventSession__c join RecordType where CventSession__c.RecordTypeId = RecordTypes.ID
```

in Soql explorer but got a Malformed query error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOQL doesn't use JOIN; instead, you query by relationships. If you want the record information along with the record type information, you can query it directly:

```
SELECT Id, Name, RecordTypeId, RecordType.Description FROM CventSession__c
```

This would produce data like the following:

```
Id,     Name    , RecordTypeId, RecordType.Description
aXX..., Record 1, 012...      , This is record type A.
aXX..., Record 2, 012...      , This is record type B.
aXX..., Record 3, 012...      , This is record type A.
aXX..., Record 4, 012...      , This is record type A.
aXX..., Record 5, 012...      , This is record type C.
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple problems:

- Don't precede the field by `CventSession__c.`
- You need to filter on a literal value in this context

You have a couple options here:

- [`Right Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Right_Inner_Join)

  ```
  SELECT ... FROM MyObject__c WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName = '<insert_literal_value>'
  ```
- [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join)

  ```
  SELECT ... FROM MyObject__c WHERE RecordTypeId IN (
      SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE DeveloperName = '<insert_literal_value>'
  )
  ```

Comment: I'm so new to SOQL taht I'm not understanding what you're explaining.  I want to get a list of the MyObject__c ID alongside the RecordType.Description field.  I don't know what all the RecordType values are ahead of time.  Is this possible?

Comment: @Dave You don't need a WHERE clause if you just want a list of record ids and the record type info; just `select Id, RecordType.Description from CventSession__c` will give you that information.